# Problems with creating a matrix with functions

Tags: functions, matrix

I have a function which gives me all the coordinates of a certain bloc in a lattice (with the help of another function for rows and columns):

```
(*
  len = length of line
x0,y0 = position of first site
lc: orientation ("r"=row, "c"=colomn)
*)
line[len_, x0_: 0, y0_: 0, rc_: "r"] := Block[{linelist, i},

  If[rc == "r",
   linelist = Table[{rx, y0}, {rx, x0, x0 + len - 1}];
   ,
   linelist = Table[{x0, ry}, {ry, y0, y0 + len - 1}];
   ];

  linelist

  ]

(*
  len(i) = length of bloc in i direction
x0,y0 = position of first site (down-left corner)
*)
bloc[lenx_, leny_, x0_: 0, y0_: 0] := Block[{bloclist},

  bloclist = {};

  For[i = y0, i < y0 + leny, i++,
   Block[{},
    bloclist = Level[Append[bloclist, line[lenx, x0, i, "r"]], {-2}];
    ]
   ];

  bloclist

  ]
```

The problem is, when I try do make this table

```
Table[bloc[a, i, 0, 7], {i, 1, 1}, {a, 1, 2}]
```

it gives me

```
{{{{0, 7}}, {{0, 7}, {1, 7}, {0, 8}, {1, 8}, {0, 9}, {1, 9}, {0, 
10}, {1, 10}, {0, 11}, {1, 11}, {0, 12}, {1, 12}, {0, 13}, {1, 
13}, {0, 14}, {1, 14}}}}
```

instead of

```
{{{{0,7}},{{0,7},{1,7}}}}
```

Where do all those other terms come from? How can I fix this?

(which is a simplified version of what I must do):

Comment: Maybe because of the way you did the Table.  If you evaluate this: Table[bloc[a, 1, 0, 7], {a, 1, 2}], it gives you (mostly) what you want.  There is one less level than what you originally expected.  {{{0, 7}}, {{0, 7}, {1, 7}}}

Comment: That said, the experiment: Table[myfun[a, i, 0, 7], {i, 1, 1}, {a, 1, 2}] yields the same as Table[myfun[a,1,0,7],{a,1,2}] so what you tried to do was reasonable.  Namely, {myfun[1, 1, 0, 7], myfun[2, 1, 0, 7]}

Comment: Actually, the outputs from the two are slightly different.  Table[myfun[a, i, 0, 7], {i, 1, 1}, {a, 1, 2}] gives {{myfun[1, 1, 0, 7], myfun[2, 1, 0, 7]}} whereas Table[myfun[a, 1, 0, 7], {a, 1, 2}] gives {myfun[1, 1, 0, 7], myfun[2, 1, 0, 7]}.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was simply because I already defined the "i" in the bloc function and used it after to calculate my table. It worked when I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

At any rate, changing up the functions a little gives the expected result.

```
line[len_, x0_: 0, y0_: 0, "r"] := Table[{rx, y0}, {rx, x0, x0 + len - 1}]
line[len_, x0_: 0, y0_: 0, rc_?Except["r"]] := Table[{rx, y0}, {rx, x0, x0 + len - 1}]
bloc[lenx_, leny_, x0_: 0, y0_: 0] := Block[{i = y0}, Nest[Level[Append[#, line[lenx, x0, i++, "r"]], {-2}] &, {}, leny]]

Table[bloc[a, i, 0, 7], {i, 1, 1}, {a, 1, 2}]
```

> {{{{0, 7}}, {{0, 7}, {1, 7}}}}